# TERM trap doesn't reliably kill backgrounded sleep process

Tags: bash, signals, kill-process, gnu-coreutils

I wrote some BASHscript that shows a spinner and noticed that sometimes after the background process would finish and I killed the spinner, the sleep process was still running and delaying processing. I reduced the code to the one below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
trap 'rm deleteme.fifo' EXIT
mkfifo deleteme.fifo
echo we are $$

bar() {
    trap 'echo killing $sleep_pid from $$; kill $sleep_pid; wait $sleep_pid; echo exit subshell; exit' TERM
    sleep 20 &
    sleep_pid=$!
    echo sleep is $sleep_pid
    echo >deleteme.fifo
    echo before wait
    wait $sleep_pid
    echo after wait
}

foo() {
    bar &
    bar_pid=$!
    read <deleteme.fifo
    kill $bar_pid && echo waiting for subshell to terminate && wait $bar_pid; echo returning
}

while true; do
    foo &
    wait $!
done
```

In `bar` I set up the trap and start a 20s sleep then notify the parent process that we are ready through a named pipe. Then I kill the child from `foo`. This often works, but sometimes the sleep survives and ticks down with the rest waiting for it. That's why I added the loop to trigger the behavior eventually. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

bash 4.4.12(1), Linux 4.14.83, coreutils 8.29

Comment: Like you wrote your script, I guess there is real-time race condition. Sometimes, the bar execution has not yet really started, the kill is already tried.

Comment: To secure against that condition I set up the deleteme.fifo. The sleep process and its PID are already known before the kill can be tried.